# Downsides to Slim as a REST API framework

Tags: php, slim

I have been experimenting with Slim for a few days now and there is a lot that I like.  However, there is one thing that nags me - when Slim is used to build a REST API it insists on putting everything into one single .php file - or even worse, a load of anonymous functions (one for each exposed REST method).

This works, that is not the issue.  However, does it not mean that when used for building any but the most trivial of APIs you are imposing an unnecessary burden on the server by getting it to load and parse a potentially really big PHP file when only a tiny percentage of its code is relevant?

If *yes*, then it begs the next question - I am a newbie to micro frameworks - is there a micro framework that does things in a way that avoids this issue?

Comment: Amount of code is going to be least of your worries. Bottleneck will be somewhere else such as your database. If you are still worried you can always use opcode cache.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php

Comment: @Mika Tuupola - a very gentle rebuke.  My question wasn't about where to find bottlenecks in my code or how to speed it up.

Comment: the title of your question isn't so clear

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure whether you are looking for a framework for a complete website or for an api alone. If latter I can recommend [restler](http://www.luracast.com/products/restler), which is a very simple, OO and stable package for developing API's.

On the other hand [Laravel](http://laravel.com) has built in [resource controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) to ease the api development, it also has a very fast growing community.

If you're looking for both a website framework ánd an api framework in one, my guess is it will be very difficult combining that into one micro framework. Laravel/Symfony and other frameworks will eventually be needed especially if you expect growth in the project.

Comment: Fair point.  I should have clarified that I am more interested in APIs rather than in a complete website.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I'll check out restler

Answer (score 1):

I made a REST API using AltoRouter:

http://altorouter.com/

I like the fact that after one route matches I can choose how to make the call, so I can point to the folder where I have all the REST controllers divided in several well organized files.

http://altorouter.com/usage/processing-requests.html

An example:

```
  function rest_data($data, $format) 
  {
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header('Content-Type: ' . $format);

            if (is_object($data) && method_exists($data, '__keepOut')) 
            {
                    $data = clone $data;
                    foreach ($data->__keepOut() as $prop) 
                    {
                            unset($data->$prop);
                    }
            }
            $options = 0;

            $json=json_encode($data, $options);

            echo $json;

  }


  $router = new AltoRouter();
  $router->setBasePath('/rest');

  $router->map('GET|POST','/', 'home#index', 'home');

  $router->map('GET','/sample_users/all', 'sample_user#all', 'sample_users_get');

  // match current request

  $match = $router->match();

  if($match && $match['name']=='home')
  {
    // write some intro

    exit();
  }

  if($match)
  {
    $target=$match['target'];

    list($class_name,$function_name) = explode("#",$target);

    require($conf["src.path"].'/rest/'.$class_name.'.php');

    foreach($_GET as $k=>$v) $match['params'][$k] = $v;

    $controller = new $class_name;
    $res = $controller->$function_name($match['params']);

    rest_data($res,RestFormat::JSON);
  }
```

Comment: I am new on StackOverflow, please tell me if I should add more details...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not so keen on the Slim PHP framework might I suggest something like [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) ? Personally I like the way Slim works, and suits what I need to build right down to a T - however I can see your frustration with creating a RESTful solution. Symfony on the other hand breaks things up a little more so you have less **fat controllers**.

If **Symfony** isn't right for you I guess you could pull out a heavyweight ike **Laravel**?

Comment: In fairness to you I have undone the downvote you got from someone else.  I had not made it clear that I was looking for a REST API framework rather than a full blown web app framework.

Comment: Ah my apologise! Thanks for undoing the downvote! I think using something like Slim for a full blown REST API framework is possible - but *it is not easy work* you would get quicker results using something built specifically for it. I wish you luck!

Comment: I had in the interim been drifting to the same conclusion myself - a framework of any kind makes is overweight for creating most REST APIs I think.  I guess a decent router is a good starting point and there are many out there - though, for my own reasons, I am currently trying to spin my own.

Comment: tbh I think I would struggle with making a Router - I mean I know what it does and everything just wouldn't be sure on the best way to do it.